# jQuery Filter Categories and highlight it's Children

Tags: jquery, filter, categories

I need to customize a script I have that filters items on a page, into categories.
It is almost working how I want it but not quite!
Here is the page: http://inspiredworx.com/dev/octavius/projects.html

What I want:
When you click on one of the category links at the bottom of the page, the little 'squares' that are children of that category, will change colour to a darker blue.

What is happening:
When I click a category, all of the squares change to a darker blue.

I understand this is happening because the css class of 'hidden' is being applied to all squares on click, and not just the children of the parent element (category link).

Could someone please help me out with my snippet here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul#filter a').click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline','none');
    $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');

    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('#portfolio .item .link.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {

        $('#portfolio .item .link a').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow').addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

});

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, on filter selection you want to fade out items not matching the filter and fade in items matching the filter.

```
function applyFilter(e){
    var target = $(e.target).closest('a');
    target
        .css('outline', 'none')
        .parent()
            .addClass('current')
            .siblings('.current')
                .removeClass('current')
    ;

    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('#portfolio .item .link.hidden').fadeIn('slow', 
            function(){ 
                $('#portfolio .item .link.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        );
    } 
    else {
        $('#portfolio .item .link a').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){$(this).addClass('hidden');});
            } else {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){$(this).removeClass('hidden');});
            }
        });   
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#filter a').click(applyFilter);
});
```